# router.post returns error "undefined is not a function" .Using mongo and express.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

[image]I'm trying to buld an app using files from [LINK](http://mherman.org/blog/2015/01/31/local-authentication-with-passport-and-express-4/#.Vphy_1UrLIX)  .I found that posting is where the code breaks.Has express js changed or is it syntax mistake ?

The router.post breaks once it reaches Maid.registerMaid(new Maid({... .I'm able to make it work using .save() but could anyone explain why this callback is beaking ?

Putting the code below.. sorry, i'm a beginner in M.E.A.N

***API.js***

```
var express = require('express'),
router = express.Router(),
passport = require('passport');
User = require('../models/user.js');
Maid = require('../models/maid.js');

router.post('/AddMaid', function(req, res) {
 console.log(req.body, req.body.FirstName,req.body.LastName);
Maid.registerMaid(new Maid({ FirstName: req.body.FirstName }), ({LastName: req.body.LastName}), function(err, account) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({err : err})
    }
    return res.status(200).json({status: 'Registration successful!'});
});
```

});

***Services.js***

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('AuthService',['$q', '$timeout', '$http',     function ($q, $timeout, $http) {

var user = null;
return ({
  isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn,
  getUserStatus: getUserStatus,
  login: login,
  logout: logout,
  register: register,
  registerMaid: registerMaid
});


function registerMaid(Fname, Lname) { 
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.post('/maid/AddMaid', {
        FirstName : Fname,
        LastName : Lname                
    }).success(function(data, status) {

        if (status === 200 && data.status) {
            deferred.resolve();
        } else {
            deferred.reject();
        }

    }).error(function(data) {
        debugger;
        alert("Error in Services AddMaid");
        deferred.reject();
    });
    return deferred.promise;
} }]);
```

***Controllers.js***

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('AddMaidController', ['$scope',        '$http','$location', 'AuthService', function($scope, $http,$location,     AuthService) {  
console.log(AuthService.getUserStatus());

$scope.register = function () {
    $scope.error = false;
    $scope.disabled = true;   
         AuthService.registerMaid($scope.registerForm.FirstName,$scope.registerForm.LastName).then(function () {            
        $scope.disabled = false;
        $scope.registerForm = {};

    }).catch(function () {
        $scope.error = true;
        $scope.errorMessage = "Something went wrong!";
    });        
};}]);
```

***maid.js***

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Maid = new Schema({
First_Name: String,
Last_Name: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('maids', Maid);
```

Comment: Could you maybe post just a little bit more code?

Comment: i'm sorry.. but i dont know which part of the code is having the error, so pasted almost entire code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you globally defined ur User and Maid modules, that is not a good practice. 
Error occurs because your Maid module (Maid model on server side, i.e. Nodejs) doesnt have registerMaid method. You need to use `Maid.create` instead